# Replacing 2003 r2 server with 2008r2. Slow client access after disconnecting 2003.

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, upgrade

After performing the following steps, network access slows down significantly when finally removing the 2003 Server:

- I added a new 2008 R2 server to an existing network with a single 2003 Server (AD and file server roles).
- Transferred the FSMO, DNS, DHCP and file shares.
- Changed the mappings on the workstations.
- Successfully removed AD from old server, nothing depends on it any more.

All works fine (main application Softdent).

As soon as I disconnect the old server, network access slows down significantly. Mostly noticeable in Softdent.

The problem goes away as soon as I connect the old server back.

How would a (seemingly) inactive 2003 server influence the speed of client access to the new one? I have a mix of Windows 7 and XP clients

Comment: What happens if you change the IP address on the 2003R2 server?

Comment: Have you updated the primary DNS record of everything to point to the new 2008 R2 server?

Comment: DNS was updated. Will try changing the server 2003 IP and report back.